# I need to add a keylistener i think

Tags: java, swing, button, text, server

I have this code that is a chat client that works with my server that im working on. In the textEnter field i want it so if you press enter it does the same action as if you click the send button. If any of you can help me find  a way to do this i will be very grateful.

```js
package TryOne;
/* Things to do
 * 1.fix (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2)  "remove spaces and new lines after text"
 * 2.fix user names not being cleared after disconnect
 * 3.fix server chat logs
 * 4.
 */
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  static String username; /* if user names don't copy to the field correctly remove static*/
  String serverIP = "localhost";
  int Port = 13;
  Socket sock;
  BufferedReader reader;
  PrintWriter writer;
  ArrayList < String > userList = new ArrayList();
  Boolean isConnected = false;
  static Boolean isPressed = false;


  /** Creates new form Chat */
  public ChatClient() {
    initComponents();
  }

  public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
      String[] data;
      String stream, done = "Done", connect = "Connect", disconnect = "Disconnect", chat = "Chat";







      /*if(isPressed){
    sendButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      sendButtonActionPerformed(evt);
      System.out.println(evt);
     }});
    isPressed = false;
   }*/

      try {
        while ((stream = reader.readLine()) != null) {

          data = stream.split(":");

          if (data[2].equals(chat)) {

            chatTextArea.append(data[0] + ": " + data[1] + "\n");
            chatTextArea.setCaretPosition(chatTextArea
              .getDocument().getLength());

          } else if (data[2].equals(connect)) {

            chatTextArea.removeAll();
            userAdd(data[0]);

          } else if (data[2].equals(disconnect)) {

            userRemove(data[0]);

          } else if (data[2].equals(done)) {

            usersList.setText("");
            writeUsers();
            userList.clear();

          }

        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
  }

  public void ListenThread() {
    Thread IncomingReader = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    IncomingReader.start();
  }

  public void userAdd(String data) {
    userList.add(data);

  }

  public void userRemove(String data) {
    chatTextArea.append(data + " has disconnected.\n");

  }

  public void writeUsers() {
    String[] tempList = new String[(userList.size())];
    userList.toArray(tempList);
    for (String token: tempList) {

      usersList.append(token + "\n");

    }

  }

  public void sendDisconnect() {

    String bye = (username + ": :Disconnect");
    try {
      writer.println(bye); // Sends server the disconnect signal.
      writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
    } catch (Exception e) {
      chatTextArea.append("Could not send Disconnect message.\n");
    }

  }


  public void Disconnect() {

    try {
      chatTextArea.append("Disconnected.\n");
      sock.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      chatTextArea.append("Failed to disconnect. \n");
    }
    isConnected = false;
    usernameField.setEditable(true);
    usersList.setText("");

  }

  /**
   * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
   * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
   * regenerated by the Form Editor.
   */
  @
  SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
  private void initComponents() {

      jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      inputTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
      jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      chatTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
      jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      usernameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
      connectButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      disconnectButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      sendButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      usersList = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
      jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
      jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
      jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Chat Client");

      inputTextArea.setColumns(20);
      inputTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
      inputTextArea.setRows(5);
      jScrollPane1.setViewportView(inputTextArea);

      chatTextArea.setColumns(20);
      chatTextArea.setEditable(false);
      chatTextArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
      chatTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
      chatTextArea.setRows(5);
      jScrollPane2.setViewportView(chatTextArea);

      jLabel1.setText("Username:");

      usernameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          usernameFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });

      connectButton.setText("Connect");
      connectButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          connectButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });

      disconnectButton.setText("Disconnect");
      disconnectButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          disconnectButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });

      sendButton.setText("Send");
      sendButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          sendButtonActionPerformed(evt);
          System.out.println(evt);
        }
      });

      usersList.setEditable(false);
      usersList.setColumns(20);
      usersList.setRows(5);
      jScrollPane3.setViewportView(usersList);

      jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      jLabel2.setText("Online Users");

      jMenu1.setText("File");

      jMenuItem1.setText("Settings");
      jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });
      jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

      jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

      setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
        getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(
          javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
          layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addContainerGap()
          .addGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addGroup(
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
              layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addGap(4, 4, 4)
              .addComponent(
                jScrollPane1,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                336,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addPreferredGap(
                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
              .addComponent(
                sendButton,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(
              jScrollPane2,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
              419,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGroup(
              layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addComponent(
                jLabel1,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                71,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addPreferredGap(
                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
              .addComponent(
                usernameField,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                153,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addPreferredGap(
                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
              .addComponent(
                connectButton)
              .addGap(18, 18,
                18)
              .addComponent(
                disconnectButton)))
          .addPreferredGap(
            javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
          .addGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(
              jLabel2,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
              Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3))
          .addContainerGap()));
      layout.setVerticalGroup(layout
        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(
          layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addContainerGap()
          .addGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(disconnectButton)
            .addComponent(connectButton)
            .addComponent(
              usernameField,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(
              jLabel1,
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
              26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2))
          .addPreferredGap(
            javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
          .addGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
              false)
            .addGroup(
              layout.createSequentialGroup()
              .addComponent(
                jScrollPane2,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                261,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addPreferredGap(
                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
              .addGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(
                  javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                  false)
                .addComponent(
                  sendButton,
                  javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                  javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                  Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(
                  jScrollPane1,
                  javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                  69,
                  Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3))
          .addContainerGap()));

      pack();
    } // </editor-fold>

  private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (isConnected == false) {
      username = usernameField.getText();
      usernameField.setEditable(false);

      try {
        sock = new Socket(serverIP, Port);
        InputStreamReader streamreader = new InputStreamReader(
          sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(streamreader);
        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        writer.println(username + ":has connected.:Connect"); // Displays
        // to
        // everyone
        // that
        // user
        // connected.
        writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
        isConnected = true; // Used to see if the client is connected.
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        chatTextArea.append("Cannot Connect! Try Again. \n");
        usernameField.setEditable(true);
      }
      ListenThread();
    } else if (isConnected == true) {
      chatTextArea.append("You are already connected. \n");
    }
  }

  private void disconnectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    sendDisconnect();
    Disconnect();
  }


  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();



  }


  private void sendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String nothing = "";
    if ((inputTextArea.getText()).equals(nothing)) {
      inputTextArea.setText("");
      inputTextArea.requestFocus();
    } else {
      try {
        writer.println(username + ":" + inputTextArea.getText() + ":" + "Chat");
        writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        chatTextArea.append("Message was not sent. \n");
      }
      inputTextArea.setText("");
      inputTextArea.requestFocus();
    }

    inputTextArea.setText("");
    inputTextArea.requestFocus();
  }

  private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // new SettingsWindow().setVisible(true);
  }

  private void usernameFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  }

  /**
   * @param args
   *            the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new ChatClient().setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  // Variables declaration - do not modify
  private javax.swing.JTextArea chatTextArea;
  private javax.swing.JButton connectButton;
  private javax.swing.JButton disconnectButton;
  private javax.swing.JTextArea inputTextArea;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
  private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
  private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
  private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
  private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
  private javax.swing.JButton sendButton;
  private javax.swing.JTextField usernameField;
  private javax.swing.JTextArea usersList;
  // End of variables declaration

}
```

Comment: FYI, the code snippets are only for Javascript

Answer (score 4):

No, never use a KeyListener in a text component. Here all you'll want is to add an ActionListener to your JTextField, the same one used on the button should work fine here.

In fact, you've already done this, but you just haven't hooked it up. Try changing this:

```
  usernameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      usernameFieldActionPerformed(evt);
    }
  });
```

to

```
  usernameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      // use the actionPerformed method you've already created for the send button
      sendButtonActionPerformed(evt);
      System.out.println(evt);
    }
  });
```

You should also avoid using NetBeans window builder to create your GUI's and instead code by hand as this will help you learn the Swing library.